# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Using YAML, how can I have the build number set to dynamically change, based on the version defined in a different file?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I'm pretty new to yaml pipelines, but trying to slowly learn..

So here is where the version is currently being set, using the `versionPrefix` and `versionSufix` variables.

I'd like to be able to pull the version from a separate file.

Is that possible? Perhaps using some inline powershell?

The main reason for this, is to allow the developers to update the version as they see fit, without needing to touch the yaml file.

```
name: $(versionPrefix)-$(versionSuffix)$(Rev:rrrr)

pool:
   name: OnPrem Windows

variables:
   buildConfiguration: release
   versionPrefix: 1.4.0
   versionSuffix: rc
```

Thanks!

Comment: I strongly recommend using GitVersion to handle versioning instead of rolling your own versioning system.

Comment: As @DanielMann said. What if 2 developers will define the same build number? There are many more cases why GitVersion is recommended for this.